# Youtube get the videos IDs of user in API v3 PHP

Tags: php, youtube

I am using this code to show all videos of a user in my website:

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/XXXXXXX/uploads');
  $server_time = $xml->updated;
  $return = array();
  foreach ($xml->entry as $video) {
      $vid = array();
      $vid['id'] = substr($video->id,42);
      $vid['title'] = $video->title;
      array_push($return, $vid);
  }

  ?>
<h2>Video Gallery</h2>
  <?php
  foreach($return as $video) {
    ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
<div style="height: auto;" class="featured-box featured-box-secundary">
  <div class="box-content clearfix">
<h4><?= $video['title'] ?></h4>
<iframe width="270" height="203" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?=$video['id']?>?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div></div></div>
    <?php
  }
?>
```

But I received a notice that is deprecated. How I can have $vid['id'] and $vid['title'] to put into HTML with API v3?

Comment: Whats the output of `$return` ? What deprecated notice are you getting ?

Comment: the notice is a extra video in the results by youtube with the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Youtube API V2 is dead.

To make requests to Youtube API V3 you need to be authenticated. Get  `{YOUR_API_KEY}` at 
 [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com). You'll need to create [new project](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and enable Youtube API.

After that, you can issue the following commands:

## First

The `channels#list` method will return a `JSON` with some information about the channel, including the `{PLAYLIST_ID}` for the "uploads" playlist:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

---

## Second

With the `{PLAYLIST_ID}` you can get the user uploaded videos with the `playlistItems#list` method:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={PLAYLIST_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

---

You can test the above code on:

[Youtube apis-explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/)

Comment: why i need to be authenticated to get a list of user's videos?

Comment: @fran No,  It wouldn't make sense if it was, it's the one you generate after creating your project on google apis console.

Comment: I want to get my channel videos not play list videos hot to do that.

Comment: @HuzoorBux No problem, use the ID for upload playlist